# query for tag ids in model

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

I have two entities in a many-to-many relationship:

```
public class SopFolder
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<SopField> SopFields { get; set; }
    }

public class SopField
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<SopFolder> SopFolders { get; set; }
    }
```

One SopFolder entity is assigned to multiple SopFields. I now want to filter the SopFolders which have certain SopFields assigned. I have an `IEnumerable<int> fieldTags` containing the SopField Id's.

How can I check if one SopFolder entity is assigned to a specific set of SopFields (for Example SopField ID 1 and 2)?

My approach (which is not working) is:

```
if(SopFolder.SopFields.Any(x => fieldTags.Contains(x.Id))) { /* do stuff */ }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a SopFolder that features *all* the SopFields assigned, then try:

```
if (SopFolder.SopFields.All(x => fieldTags.Contains(x.Id))) { /* do stuff */ }
```

Comment: This actually pointed me to the right direction. My Initial query was correct, but I used it in a wrong way.

Comment: Glad I could help?  Sort of?  :)

Answer (score 0):

This query is correct and working. I just used in a wrong way in a recursive Folder Loop.

```
if(SopFolder.SopFields.Any(x => fieldTags.Contains(x.Id))) { /* do stuff */ }
```